# Dynamically adding deleting and adding in a table in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to dynamically create a table(containing 3columns) that selects value from two drop-downs and inserts in two columns of a table. The table can gave Max 5 row.
 The dynamic creation occurs when I click on the add link placed next to the drop-down. The third column consists of a link delete that deletes the row if clicked.

I need to store and delete(if delete is clicked) the column values as well.

While dynamically i create the table I created a row id that is the row count. I did it because while deleting the row count was altering but corresponding to the row Id I could pick the column values.

Now the problem is after deleting say row 3rd row out of 5 rows. I insert a new row it's count would be 5 and the row id now becomes 5 and my column values replaces the original ones for 5th row.
How do I insert a new row ??
I want to do it without using jquery

Please find my code here:-

```
addRow()
 { 
var myName = document.getElementById("name"); 
var age = document.getElementById("age"); 
var table = document.getElementById("myTableData"); 
var rowCount = table.rows.length; 
var row = table.insertRow(rowCount); row.insertCell(0).innerHTML= '<input type="button" value = "Delete" onClick="deleteRow(this)">'; row.insertCell(1).innerHTML= myName.value; row.insertCell(2).innerHTML= age.value; 
row.id = rowCount;
var testValone= 'colone';
var colVal = testVar + rowCount;
var testValtwo = 'coltwo';
var colValTwo = testValtwo + rowCount; 
// there are 10 global variables storing the col value
//colVal1, colVal2.... colVal5 
//colValTwo1.... colValTwo5
// store the inner HTML values accordingly everytime the function is called.
} 

function deleteRow(obj) 
{ 
var index = obj.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
 var table = document.getElementById("myTableData"); 
var id = obj.parentNode.parentNode.id

var testValone= 'colone';
var colVal = testValone + id;
var testValtwo = 'coltwo';
var colValTwo = testValtwo + id; 
table.deleteRow(index); // issue comes here after deleting when added.
//global variables are set to null.
}⁠⁠⁠⁠
```

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: post your `javascript` too

Comment: Use the id for the dynamic id generation, but use the row count to limit the number of rows that can be added

Answer (score 0):

Your current problem is rather the way you handle / store your data, you have to look at it in the following way:

When you add data, you set the index of your row based on your current length, like for example

```
#0 Row 1
#1 Row 2
#2 Row 3
#3 Row 4
```

Now deleting #3 is not a problem, then next add will be correct, however, deleting any row other than #3 leads to the following data structure

```
#0 Row 1
#2 Row 3
#3 Row 4
```

After which adding another row, leads to this complicated, incorrect view, eg:

```
#0 Row 1
#2 Row 3
#3 Row 4
#3 Row 5
```

Your current deletion works with the records based on the index you generate when adding the row. Now you have 2 direct solutions. One way would be to recalculate any of the following indexes after removal, so if I take the list of items from above, we could recalculate it like this

```
#0 Row 1 
#2 Row 3 -> #1 Row 3
#3 Row 4 -> #2 Row 4
```

Or, we could keep a dataset, like an array to hold all the items you have added, and upon adding insert a new row, and upon deleting check the index inside the dataset that would relate to the index in the table you wish to delete.

Code for version 1 (updating the indices in the table, probably most similar to your code)

```js
function getTable() {
  return document.getElementById('mytable');
}

function addRow() {
  var table = getTable();
  if (!addRow.id) {
    // keep internal id
    addRow.id = 0;
  }
  var id = addRow.id;
  var row = table.insertRow();
  row.insertCell().innerHTML = '#' + id;
  row.insertCell().innerHTML = 'Row ' + id;
  row.insertCell().innerHTML = '<button type="button" onclick="deleteRow(this)">delete</button>';
  row.setAttribute('index', table.rows.length - 1);
  // increase internal id
  addRow.id++;
}

function deleteRow( buttonInRow ) {
  var rowIndex = buttonInRow.parentNode.parentNode.getAttribute('index'), 
      i, table = getTable();
  table.deleteRow( rowIndex );
  for (i = rowIndex; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
    // updates the indexes of the following rows (if any)
    table.rows[i].setAttribute('index', i);
  }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="addRow()">Add</button>
<table id="mytable" class="table">
<tr class="header"><td>#</td><td>data</td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

Code for version 2 (keeping data outside of table)

```js
// your global dataset and key
var data = [], id = 0;

function getTable() {
  return document.getElementById('mytable');
}

function addRow() {
  var table = getTable();
  var row = table.insertRow();
  row.insertCell().innerHTML = '#' + id;
  row.insertCell().innerHTML = 'Row ' + id;
  row.insertCell().innerHTML = '<button type="button" onclick="deleteRow(' + id + ')">delete</button>';
  data.push(id); // could theoretically be your full dataset ofcourse
  // increase the id number
  ++id;
}

function deleteRow( idValue ) {
  var table = getTable(),
    index = data.indexOf( idValue ); // if you pushed your full dataset, you need to determine the index in a different way
  // index + 1 because we don't delete the header row, without header row, it would be index
  table.deleteRow( index + 1 ); 
  // remove the row from your datatable
  data.splice( index, 1);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="addRow()">Add</button>
<table id="mytable">
<tr><td>#</td><td>Data</td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

**Answer before update**

You can see a basic example here, the id is an internal variable that gets managed throughout the application life cycle, however you can dynamically add/delete items in the table, as the current row count of the table is checked through the data array

I tried commenting the code a litte ;)

```js
// will be assigned in the onload function
var deleteItem;

// attach to the loading function
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  // contains the data as objects
  var data = [];
  // contains the internal id
  var _id = 0;
  // gets the elements once, and use them throughout the code
  var template = document.querySelector('#template');
  var newButton = document.querySelector('#btnNew');
  var txtName = document.querySelector('#txtName');
  var txtValue = document.querySelector('#txtValue');
  var rows = document.querySelector('#rows');
  
  // updates the add button to disable/enable
  function updateButtons() {
    if (data.length >= 5) {
      newButton.setAttribute('disabled', true);
    } else {
      newButton.removeAttribute('disabled' );
    }
  }
  
  // removes the data from the text buttons
  function resetForm() {
    txtName.value = '';
    txtValue.value = '';
    updateButtons();
  }
  
  // gets the element from the template filled with the data given
  function getElementFromTemplate( row ) {
    var divElem = template.innerHTML, newElem = document.createElement('div');
    for (var prop in row){
      if (row.hasOwnProperty( prop )) {
        divElem = divElem.split('{ ' + prop + ' }').join( row[prop] );
      }
    }
    newElem.innerHTML = divElem;
    return newElem;
  }
  
  // deletes an item from the ui + data
  deleteItem = (id) => {
    // get the row that got clicked
    var row = document.querySelector('#row-' + id).parentNode, i;
    // removes it from the ui
    rows.removeChild(row);
    // searches the item
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      if (data[i].id === id) {
        break;
      }
    }
    // removes the data from the array at this index
    data.splice(i, 1);
    // calls the form to check if it's valid now to add the buttons
    updateButtons();
  };

  // adds a new item
  newButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    // create a new data item
    var item = { id: ++_id, name: txtName.value, text: txtValue.value };
    // add it to the data
    data.push( item );
    // add the value to the html
    rows.appendChild( getElementFromTemplate( item ) );
    // and reset the form ( empty texts + handle enable/disable add button)
    resetForm();
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <div id="header">
  <input type="text" id="txtName" />
  <input type="text" id="txtValue" />
  <button type="button" id="btnNew">Add</button>
  </div>
  <div id="rows">
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/template" id="template">
  <div class="row" id="row-{ id }">
    <div><button type="delete" onclick="deleteItem({ id })">Delete</button></div>
    <div>{ id }</div>
    <div>{ name }</div>
    <div>{ text }</div>
  </div>
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but could you have a look at my code snippet, And help me improve my code

Comment: if there are 5 rows say the index start from 0 to 4, if i delete row 3rd row now the new index is from 0-3 and the old 4th index is now 3 however the id would remain as 4, Now if a new row is added the rowCount becomes 4 and correspondingly the id becomes 4 n the new global variables become colVal4 and colValTwo4 and the exiting value would be replaced. I think when i am deleting i need to update the global variables but i am getting stuck with it. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @ManowaraChowdhury sure I can check, in how far does the answer so far doesn't help you?

Comment: I have been trying to implement a dynamic functionality that as not been done ever in my project and now all seems to work except for one scenario where on deleting randomly( i mean not in an organised way which might happen for real) if a new row is added it won't function. not very strong in Javascript but when i ran the code you provided i am feeling a little lost as i am unable to sync it with my code. Changing a logic now would alter a lot however just trying to look for a easy way.

Comment: @ManowaraChowdhury I added some information for you on the question, let me know if this helps you enough, a code update I can still do though

Comment: Thank you tried something similar on the lines :) appreciate your help